# AWS Lambda Python script not iterating through 'aws_account_numbers' as expected

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function written in Python 3.7, The function is set to delete snapshots older than 120 days. I'm running this from a management account and hitting 2 child accounts using  'aws_account_numbers'. The function runs successfully but in CloudWatch the logs show the same snapshots being deleted for each account. The log shows snapshot x y z is deleted for accountA but then it shows the same snapshots x y z  being deleted for accountB. What is really happening is that all of these snapshots do not live in accountA or accountB but they actually live in the management account.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import boto3
import collections
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

region ='us-east-1'

aws_account_numbers = {"accountA":"xxxxxxxxxxxx", "accountB":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=120)
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    snapshots = ec2_resource.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self'])

    for name, acctnum in aws_account_numbers.items():
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/EOTSS-Snapshot-Cleanup-120days" % acctnum
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
        ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
                
        for snapshot in snapshots:
            try:
                if not snapshot.description.startswith('Snapshot created by task soe-backup') and delete_time > snapshot.start_time:
                    #snapshot.delete()
                    print ("Snapshot %s is deleted in acct: %s" % (snapshot, acctnum))
                
            except ClientError as e:
                if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidSnapshot.InUse':
                    print ("Snapshot %s in use in acct: %s" % (snapshot, acctnum))
                    continue
                                                
                else:
                    print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
                    continue
                
    return 'Execution Complete'
```

Comment: You are calling `snapshots = ec2_resource` on your managment account. It should be called after you assume role for the other accoutns.

Comment: What you are saying makes logical sense to me, I made that change plus fixed the indentations but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post my new code here but the line 'snapshots = ec2_resource.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self']) ' has been moved down under the 'for name, acctnum' section.